# handle longer values in dropdown list

Tags: vba, excel

I have a drop-down list in excel form which has values in it that don't fit in a single line due to length restrictions of drop-down list. Is there a solution for this?

Can I increase the width of the dropdown list and display longer values in two lines instead of one?

Any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: How long is the string? The reason why I ask is because AFAIK, you can show the `longer values` only by increasing the column width. Technically you can increase the column width when the user selects the cell which has the Data Validation and then resize it again back to normal once user selects some other cell in `Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)` event

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the behaviour is what you want but this gives an idea of what is possible

```
Option Explicit

Dim origColWidth As Double

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Const avgcharperStdColumn As Long = 8 'avg characters in col width 8.43
Const defaultColumnWidth As Double = 8.43 'Default column width

Dim dataValCell As Range
Dim cellVal As Validation
Dim splitString() As String
Dim newColWidth As Double
Dim i As Long
Dim maxStrLength As Long


    'Set cell with data validation
    Set dataValCell = Sheet1.Range("G5") 'Define which cell contains validation

    'Check selection intersects required cell
    'Also check only 1 cell is selected
    If Not Intersect(Target, dataValCell) Is Nothing _
        And Target.Rows.Count = 1 And Target.Columns.Count = 1 Then

        'capture current width to allow reset
        origColWidth = Target.ColumnWidth

        'access the validation list in the cell
        Set cellVal = dataValCell.Validation

        'Split the contents into an array and cycle to find longest string
        splitString = Split(cellVal.Formula1, ",")
        For i = LBound(splitString) To UBound(splitString)
            If Len(splitString(i)) > maxStrLength Then maxStrLength = Len(splitString(i))

        Next i

        'VERY crude method to calc how many chars fit column - needs more work :)
        newColWidth = (maxStrLength / avgcharperStdColumn) * defaultColumnWidth
        If newColWidth > origColWidth Then
            dataValCell.ColumnWidth = newColWidth
        End If

    'if variable set and not intersecting validation cell then reset column width
    ElseIf origColWidth > 0 Then
        dataValCell.ColumnWidth = origColWidth

    End If

End Sub
```